# File Output vs Properties/Output properties

Tags: rendering

If want to use just the  File Output node (in a batch render process)  the default output (in properties/output properties/output) becomes redundant  so is there a way to turn if off?
Ideally just removing the properties/output properties file path  should do it but Blender just errors and fails to produce any renders at all.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Robert but removing the composite node (and the viewer node) still produces a render  based on whatever is in the properties/output properties/output settings.
It appears it  needs a switch to turn it off if you only need an output from the File output node but this does not exist.

Comment: If you are rendering an animation, then it will indeed still output the result to the specified directory and is no option to disable this as far as I'm aware.